# JNI call crashes with NoSuchMethodError only when used as .aar library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-library, aar

I have made an Android library project that wraps the C++ native code and exposes it as Java API. In the native code I call some custom Java class methods through standard JNI calls. Here is a simplified example:

### JAVA:

```
public class CustomClass {
    private int myInt;

    public CustomClass(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

    public int getMyInt() {
        return myInt;
    }
}

public class ApiClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myNativeLibrary");
    }

    private native void jniDoStuffWithCustomClass(CustomClass customClass);

    public void doStuffWithCustomClass(CustomClass customClass) {
        jniDoStuffWithCustomClass(customClass);
    }
}
```

### C++:

```
void jniDoStuffWithCustomClass(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject customObj)
{
    jclass classref = env->GetObjectClass(customObj);
    jmethodID midGetMyInt = env->GetMethodID(classref, "getMyInt", "()I");
    jint val = env->CallIntMethod(customObj, midGetMyInt);
    // Do something with int...
}
```

I use the library in my project by calling `new ApiClass().doStuffWithCustomClass(new CustomClass(5));`

This works perfectly well in instrumentation tests and when I add the library dependency to the demo-app module in the same library project. But when I import my-library.aar in another project I get `NoSuchMethodError` exception when executing `env->CallIntMethod(customObj, midGetMyInt)` in the native code.

To make things even weirder, if I call `CustomClass.getMyInt()` from Java before calling the native method in this new project there is no crash:

```
final CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass(5);
customClass.getMyInt(); // This call makes things not crash???
new ApiClass().doStuffWithCustomClass(customClass);
```

Of course, I don't want to call every single class method in Java before using the library API. So, can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: not sure but seems it is related to https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

Comment: @pskink: How so? The OP doesn't appear to be using any cached local references in the native code.

Comment: @Michael thats why i said "not sure", notice that if OP has a reference in a local variable `final CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass(5);` it works but when passing `new CustomClass(5)` directly to native method that object is not attached to any reference...

Comment: @pskink I don't think it has do with holding a reference because it crashes regardless of it. The thing that prevents it from crashing is calling the method in Java before calling it in the native code. Like JNI cannot find any of my library classes methods unless they are invoked in Java first.
It also crashes if I try to call class constructor from the native code, but if I construct some dummy object of the same class in Java before than I can also create a new object for that class in the native code.
And that happens only when I use it as .aar file, original library project works fine.

Comment: hmm strange, so if you use "normal" jars it works fine? really weird...

Comment: @pskink if I use it as a module inside the demo app in the library project or in the library instrumentation tests then it works. I didn't try with "normal" jar, how would I create plain jar with JNI code in it?

Comment: good point ;-), seems that only aar can have native code inside